# How Selenium 4 NetworkInterceptor works internally

Tags: java, selenium-webdriver, bidirectional

In Selenium 4 , there is provision to intercept network by below code:

```java
NetworkInterceptor interceptor = new NetworkInterceptor(
      driver,
      Route.matching(req -> true)
        .to(() -> req -> new HttpResponse()
          .setStatus(200)
          .addHeader("Content-Type", MediaType.HTML_UTF_8.toString())
          .setContent(utf8String("Creamy, delicious cheese!"))));
```

my question is that I never use that variable interceptor, then how or who usage it?

Comment: Not sure what you problem is. You have just provided a usage example. Can you please narrow down the problem?

Comment: In this example which I have taken from Selenium website, they say that just create an object of NetworkInterceptor. aftger creating this object, I never used that object (interceptor) in my code, so I am curious, how the system know that this object has to be called by some internal process? 

instead of NetworkInterceptor interceptor = new NetworkInterceptor(........)
if I just use below statement
new NetworkInterceptor(...........)
then also it works..... so how this object is used internally ?

Comment: instead of NetworkInterceptor interceptor = new NetworkInterceptor(........)
if I just use below statement
new NetworkInterceptor(...........), 
then also it works..... so how this object is used internally ? 

I mean, suppose I create an object, then generally I use thatlike below
Obj a = new Obj();
a.dosomething()  or System.register(a) something of this sort, but in the above case I did nothing of that sort.

so my question is how the system know that there is an object of NetworkInterceptor created and that has to be used?

Comment: I just explored further and found that here the constructor of the class NetworkInterceptor plays the role, maybe either running a separate thread or a service.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you look inside `NetworkInterceptor` sources:

```java
  public NetworkInterceptor(WebDriver driver, Filter filter) {
    Require.nonNull("WebDriver", driver);
    Require.nonNull("HTTP filter", filter);

    if (!(driver instanceof HasDevTools)) {
      throw new IllegalArgumentException("WebDriver instance must implement HasDevTools");
    }

    this.tools = ((HasDevTools) driver).getDevTools();
    tools.createSessionIfThereIsNotOne();

    tools.getDomains().network().interceptTrafficWith(filter);
  }
```

you will see that when you create an object with `new` it actually establishes a special kind of connection between your code and your driver:

```java
this.tools = ((HasDevTools) driver).getDevTools();
tools.createSessionIfThereIsNotOne()
```

and then configures "stub" on driver side through that connection:

```java
tools.getDomains().network().interceptTrafficWith(filter);
```

After that your client code does not need a reference to `NetworkInterceptor` (except of closing it but since it is `AutoCloseable` you should use it within `try with resources` block) because all the setup already configured for WebDriver.

Also what you can pick from those sources is that the interceptor won't always works. It only works with drivers supporting DevTools such as: Chrominum, Chrome, Edge, Firefox

Comment: Thank you a lot Alexey for clarifying this to me, it really helps.