# How to use selenium NetworkInterceptor with RemoteWebDriver

Tags: java, selenium-webdriver, selenium-grid

Is there a way to use Selenium 4 `NetworkInterceptor` on CI using `RemoteWebDriver`?

```
URL seleniumHubUrl = null; // Selenium Hub URL
RemoteWebDriver driver = new RemoteWebDriver(seleniumHubUrl, new DesiredCapabilities())
new NetworkInterceptor(driver, (Filter) next -> next))
```

Results with `DevTools Unable to create DevTools connection` exception which make sense as `RemoteWebDriver` simply doesn't implement `HasDevTools` interface. Yet, it doesn't seem feasible to use `ChromeDriver` or `ChromiumDriver` instead of `RemoteWebDriver` as I can't pass selenium hub URL while constructing an instance.

Is there a way to work-around this so that I can mock request/response in tests that need to run regularly on CI?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/a/76361920/175554 may help

Comment: Thanks, but not really. It just explain how it is being registered by creating a new instance.